# Runtime erro in the Callback where got the return for called another DLL dynamically

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, dll, dynamic, callback

I try to be more clear this time.
I have a main program for test that call Sinacor.DLL that for it turn call PasswordManager.dll a 3er part dll without code (its a IDM system);

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
Sinacor.DLL
...code ....
LPSTR  *GetSenha (int FAR nicas)  
.... code..... 
char * Mypwd = NULL; // for return porpouse
Mypwd = call dynamically PasswordManager.dll // works fine
return Mypwd; } // return the encrypted password, in test case return "sinacor01"
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>

Sinacor..h

extern "C" {     LPSTR FAR *GetSenha(int); }

>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
the Sinacor.dll is also loaded dynamically too in the main program for testing:
the main  code: 

.....some code ..............                   
typedef LPSTR (CALLBACK *ULPRET)(int);         
LPSTR   Mypwd = " ";
hLib = LoadLibrary ( "C:\\Ricardo\\Sinacor\\Sinacor.dll");

lpfnDLLProc = (ULPRET) GetProcAddress (hLib,"GetSenha");      

Mypwd =   (*lpfnDLLProc)(0); //Got runtime error in this statement
```

I now is a parameter convention error that why I complied both (main and Sinacor.dll) as a C programs with C conventions. The stack show all modules as a C module with C conventions Should works but isn´t .
Please advice.

both programs were complited with _cstl (like CALLBACK).